# Send Joystick commands over BLE

Tags: c, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, adafruit

I'm doing a joystick with an Adafruit Feather 32u4 with 2 74hc165 to shift in all my 17 buttons I need. Everything done so far, but I'm kinda new to BLE devices and I don't know how to send data via bluetooth. Can anyone help me understand?

The libraries I'm using are [ArduinoShiftIn](https://github.com/InfectedBytes/ArduinoShiftIn) and [ArduinoJoystickLibrary](https://github.com/MHeironimus/ArduinoJoystickLibrary)

Here's my actual code:

```
    #include <ShiftIn.h>
#include <Joystick.h>
#include <Arduino.h>

Adafruit_BluefruitLE_SPI ble(BLUEFRUIT_SPI_CS, BLUEFRUIT_SPI_IRQ, BLUEFRUIT_SPI_RST);

ShiftIn<2> shift;
Joystick_ joystick;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  shift.begin(22, 23, 0, 1  );
  joystick.begin();
}

void loop() {
  /* analog */
  joystick.setXAxis(analogRead(18));
  joystick.setYAxis(analogRead(19));
  joystick.setRxAxis(analogRead(20));
  joystick.setRyAxis(analogRead(21));

  /* shift in */
  if (shift.update()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < shift.getDataWidth(); i++)
      joystick.setButton(i, shift.state(i));
  }
}
```

Thanks to you all.

Answer (score 0):

There are per-made Bluetooth libraries for Arduino which works like sending data over serial interface.
There is a Arduino library and example [here](https://github.com/jdunmire/HC05), which uses HC05 Bluetooth module to send and receive data. You can connect it to your PC/laptop and get this data there. This [instructable](https://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-AND-Bluetooth-HC-05-Connecting-easily/) explains how to do that.
Hope this helps. Cheers.